# How to create a lookup relationship with Contact (Email) in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How do I create a lookup relationship with a Contact in salesforce? I am trying to create related list between custom object and a contact. Custom object data is based on the contacts email address (but not on contact ID).

Any kind of help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom field to your custom Object that is of type Lookup(Contact).  See Setup->Create->Objects->.  Then scroll to the Custom Fields section.

Comment: Let me know if i answer your question?